# Not able to upload file in Spring Web Project using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, file-upload

I am trying to read excel file to save the records inside the file into database.

Below is my html code :

```
<div ng-controller = "myCtrl">
<input type="file" file-model="myFile"/>
<button ng-click="uploadFile()">upload me</button>
</div>
```

I am using this Javascript code to read the file :

```
$scope.uploadFile = function(){
var file = $scope.myFile;
console.log('file is ' );
console.dir(file);
$http({
method : "POST",
url : "/Example/fileUpload",
data : file
 }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
 console.log(response);
}, function myError(response) {
console.log(response);
});
};
```

Also, the java code I have written to handle this is :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/fileUpload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> checkTestMapping(@RequestBody Object file){
System.out.println(file);
return null;
}
```

It is giving me the following error after I select a file (excel file) and click upload.

error: "Unsupported Media Type"
​​
message: "Content type 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8' not supported"
​​
path: "/Example/fileUpload"
​​
status: 415
​​
timestamp: "2018-06-14T17:11:27.494+0000"

Can someone help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to accept MultipartFile type instead of generic Object type-

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/fileUpload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> checkTestMapping(@NotNull @RequestBody MultipartFile file){

}
```

Comment: Thanks. It is now hitting my java code but the file object is coming as null.

Comment: That's your angular-side problem. I used a module this module to upload file from angularjs - https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload. Please mark the answer as accepted if it solved your controller problem. Feel free to ask me further questions if you need help.

Comment: Can you help me with the Angular Side issue also. Thanks.

Comment: Umm not sure though but can you try this and give me  a feedback - 
data: {
                    'file': file
                }

Comment: Still facing the same issue.

Comment: Can you look into ng-file-upload and try using that? It's pretty simple.